# Finding unique example sentences from a list for a list of words

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, substring

I have a list of 3000 (mostly unique) words sorted by their frequency in English. I also have a list of 3000 unique sentences. Ideally I would like to use Python to generate a list of one example sentence for the use of each word. So each word would have a sentence, which contains that word, paired with it. But no sentence should be paired with more than one word and no word should have more than one sentence associated with it.

But here is the catch, this is a messy dataset, so many words are going to appear in more than one sentence, some words will only appear in one sentence, and many words will not appear in any of the sentences. So I'm not going to get my ideal result. Instead, what I would like is an optimal list with the greatest number of sentences matched with words. And then a list of sentences that were omitted. Also, ideally, the sorted list should prefer to find sentences for lower frequency words than for higher frequency ones. (Since it will be easier to go back and find replacement sentences for higher frequency words.)

Here is an abbreviated example to help clarify:

```
words = ["the", "cat", "dog", "fish", "runs"]
sentences = ["the dog and cat are friends", "the dog runs all the time", "the dog eats fish", "I love to eat fish", "Granola is yummy too"]
output = ["", "the dog and cat are friends", "the dog eats fish", "I love to eat fish", "the dog runs all the time"]
omitted = ["Granola is yummy too"]
```

As you can see:

- "Granola is yummy too" was omitted because it doesn't contain any of the words.
- "the dog and cat are friends" was matched with "cat" because it is the only sentence that contains "cat"
- "the dog runs all the time" was matched with "runs" because it is the only sentence that contains "runs"
- "the dog eats fish" was matched with "dog" because "dog" is less frequent than "the" in English
- "I love to eat fish" was matched with "fish" because the only other sentence with "fish" was already used
- "the" didn't have any sentences left that matched with it

I'm not sure where to even start writing the code for this. (I'm a linguist who dabbles in coding on the side, not a professional coder.) So any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> ...where to even start...

Here is a kind of naive approach without any attempt to optimize.

- make a dictionary with the words as the keys and a list for the value

  - ```
    {'word1':[], 'word2':[], ...}
    ```
- for each item in the dictionary

  - iterate over the sentences and append a sentence to the item's list if the word is in the sentence

---

Or maybe:

- make a set of the words
- make an empty dictionary
- for each sentence

  - find the intersection of the words-in-the-sentence with the set of words
  - add an item to the dictionary using the sentence for the key and the *intersection* for the value